# UIStackView - Want a percentage to define each item

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uistackview

I want to put two views into a UIStackView. I want the top item to always be 30% of the space no matter what device (or orientation) that it appears. Thus, I want to have the bottom view to be 70%. How do I tell a UIStackView that I want to use a percentage?

[Example resulting view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln1v1.png)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just set a constraint for the top view.

In the storyboard's **Document Outline** control-drag from the top view to the stack view and select `Equal heights`. This will make their heights equal. Now go to the **Size Inspector** and you should see the constraint. Double click on it and set the **multiplier** to 0.3. Then update the frames.

If the bottom view doesn't automatically size or it gives you an error telling that you need a height constraint, just repeat the process, but now set the multiplier to 0.7.

Comment: This works, but make sure the stackview is set to Alignment: Fill and Distribution: Fill

Comment: This worked for me...also refer https://medium.com/@jasmine.nitin27/weight-assignment-in-stack-view-percentage-wise-size-calculation-37ee0591bf1e

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.2**

**To implement this programmatically**

Setting `UIView` to always be 30% of the size of it's superview within a `UIStackView`

```
viewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
```

---

Full code implementation:

```
// Configure the StackView
let stackView = UIStackView()

stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .fill
view.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

// Configure View A
let viewA = UIView()
viewA.backgroundColor = .darkGray
viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Configure View B
let viewB = UIView()
viewB.backgroundColor = .lightGray
viewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Add Views to StackView
stackView.addArrangedSubview(viewA)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(viewB)

// Set the height percentage multiplier to View A
viewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 2):

From apple documentation

> UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally A layout where the stack
>   view resizes its arranged views so that they fill the available space
>   along the stack view’s axis. Views are resized proportionally based on
>   their intrinsic content size along the stack view’s axis.

So according to this you should set `UIStackView` `distribution` property to `UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally` and set `intrinsic size`, its.

You can get more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStackViewDistribution) and on [Intrinsic content size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW21)